# ms dynamics crm. how to share variables between plugins of different types

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm

I have two plugin PreEntityUpdate and PostEntityAssign. Inside update PostEntityUpdate I execute assign and it invokes PostEntityAssign plugin execution. Is it possible to pass shared variables from PreEntityUpdate to PostEntityAssign? I tried but unsuccessfully...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should look through the ALL parent context of your plugin and try to find necessary shared data into the SharedVariables collections.
Here is an example of code:

```
 public new void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        string sharedDataKey = "your key defined here";
        bool found = false;

        IPluginExecutionContext currentContext = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

        // Find shared data among parent contexts
        IPluginExecutionContext context = currentContext;
        while (context != null)
        {
            if (context.SharedVariables.ContainsKey(sharedDataKey))
            {
                found = true;
                break;
            }

            context = context.ParentContext;
        }

        object sharedData = null;
        if (found)
        {
            // Data was found in parent context
            sharedData = context.SharedVariables[sharedDataKey];
        }
        else
        {
            // Data was NOT found in parent context, thereby we create new one
            sharedData = new object();
            currentContext.SharedVariables[sharedDataKey] = sharedData;
        }

        // Do what you want with 'sharedData'
    }
```

Something very similar I used for situation that you described.
Namely, I have one PRE update entity plugin that sometime update related entity which immediately leads to calling another instance of my plugin.